# xvfb-run hanging on server

Tags: selenium, bamboo, xvfb

On our build server (bamboo launched) we are wanting to do selenium tests, to do this we are running xvfb-run, this works on our local servers which are all of the same type.

If I log on to the build server and run:
`xvfb-run echo 'i'`
I get the error:
`xvfb-run: error: Xvfb failed to start`

I have tried running like this:
`xvfb-run -a echo 'i'`
This time it just hangs and never finishes, any ideas on things I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your problem, are u trying to run your selenium tests in your build server with the xvfb? Which driver are u using?

Comment: its just using xvfb-run to run headless tests for behat testing, selenium/mink is the driver, so it uses the selenium jar file - similar to basically running `java selenium.jar` which doesn't run it headless, so using xvfb-run to make it headless

Answer (score 1):

Run following commands:

```
sudo nohup Xvfb :40 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:40
```

Comment: Running this gave the following response: `[1] 562` followed by `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'output.out'` but never actually comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works locally, I suspect a server or permissions issue is going on.  Perhaps your user can't open up a lock file in /tmp ? Try to get more info about the problem by running:

```
xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout [mycommand]
```

Comment: The error received is: 
    
    `(EE) Fatal server error:
    (EE) Server is already active for display 99
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X99-lock
    and start again.
    (EE)`

Comment: Well, that seems self explanatory.  There's a lock file, so either you have a problem from a previous run or there's another process taking up that display.  Get everything cleanly stopped, remove the lock file(s) and try again.

Comment: Its not from a previous run as its a brand new server booted from bamboo... i've deleted that lock file, but get the exact same error.

Comment: Any success on this?

Comment: Any success on this? No output and just hanging on when executing `xvfb-run -e /dev/stdout [mycommand]`